# How can I measure the power consumption of the different devices connected to my computer?

Tags: graphics-card, power-supply

I recently bought a new graphics card and I want to see  if I am going to run into problems trying to use it with my desktop's measly 300W power supply. I am running Ubuntu 14.04.

Is there anyway that I can monitor the power consumption of the different devices that are plugged into my computer, such as the monitor(s), CPU, graphics card, keyboard, mouse etc ?

Answer (score 1):

I won't recommend a specific product, but you could use a "Plug-In Power and Energy Monitor", similar to the below:

[image: Power Usage Monitor]

Since you'll be plugging the power cable from the PSU to the energy monitor, you'll be able to accurately determine the total power consumption. There's no software solution that I would consider accurate, so a hardware solution is recommended.

Your monitors don't enter the equation since they're not being powered by the PSU.

Most solutions will have numerous measurement options (including Watts).